# Correct way to do a Response.Redirect from one page to another on the same site

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

I'm sure this has been asked time and time again.  And yes I've searched.  However, I'm unable to find an example that clearly demonstrates what I'm looking to accomplish.

I'm currently on `mywebsite/test.aspx`, I want to Redirect to `mywebsite/testing.aspx`. However I want this redirect to work both live on server and within debug of visual studio.  I've tried

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace(Request.RawUrl,"testing.aspx"))
```

However this replaces the whole thing.

Hope this makes sense - `mywebsite/test.aspx` should redirect to `mywebsite/testing.aspx`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use application relative urls. `~/` represents the application root path, so it will work for both `/` and `/virtual-directory/`.

```
Response.Redirect("~/testing.aspx");
```

Answer (score 7):

If your page is on the same directory level you can just use:

```
Response.Redirect("testing.aspx", false);
```

If your page is on application root you can use following command:

```
Response.Redirect("~/testing.aspx", false);
```

And finally, if you page is inside sub directory from current page you can use:

```
Response.Redirect("MyFolder/testing.aspx", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use url relative to web site root.
These urls always start with `/` which means 'root'

For `Response.Redirect` and any other url you know will be processed by server (like url specified in server control) it's better to start url with `~/` as root, this will help with virtual directories mess.